# Realm , Object is already managed by another Realm

Tags: ios, realm

1. Use realm to save data.
2. Config the realm use defaultconfig.
3. then , I addOrUpdate some `RLMModels`
4. It's success.
5. I changed the config use

   ```
   RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
   config.fileURL = [[[config.fileURL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myname"] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"realm"];
   [RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config];
   ```
6. I `addOrUpdate` the same `RLMModels`
7. console print error:

   ```
   2017-11-09 10:50:18.293801+0800 LNLibBase_Example[96588:8779968]
   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException',
   reason: 'Object is already managed by another Realm. 
   Use create instead to copy it into this Realm.'
   ```

Comment: What part of the error message are you having trouble with? A given object can only belong to one Realm at a time. If you want to copy it into a different Realm, you need to use `+createOrUpdateInRealm:withValue:`.

Comment: I package a class to manage the operation. The .h file provide addOrUpdate: method,and chnageDatabase: method,When someone use the class,may addOrupdate: then,he invokes changeDatabase: ,next invoke addOrUpdate: ,finilly error, how can I do ,he uses the methods is safe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message states, an object that is already managed by a Realm cannot be added to a different Realm. What you can do instead is create a *copy* of it in a different Realm using [`+createInRealm:withValue:`](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#/c:objc(cs)RLMObject(cm)createInRealm:withValue:).

Comment: I want to changed the database ,I need chenged the config like this: `RLMRealmConfiguration *config = [RLMRealmConfiguration defaultConfiguration];
    config.fileURL                = [[[config.fileURL URLByDeletingLastPathComponent] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"myname"] URLByAppendingPathExtension:@"realm"];
    [RLMRealmConfiguration setDefaultConfiguration:config];` .Then I can't use older RLMModels? I need create new RLMModels?

Comment: If you change the file URL in the configuration, you are opening a _different_ database, not the same one. So yes, you can't put models from the original database in the new database, you need new model objects.